# jquery scrolling images don't appear all the images

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this code to scroll images... but the problem is I only can see 4 images while I put 8 images in the code..

index.html: pastebin.com/yL5Jqvpb

css file: pastebin.com/iPwfNCBu

jquery.simplyscroll.js: pastebin.com/RXCnXakQ

jquery.simplyscroll.min.js: http://pastebin.com/V9KgLN5S

and here is the page link: http://www.abdoyaacoub.com/home/brands/brands.html

what do you think is the problem? why only 4 pics appear?

Comment: I can see there was some problem with your css and now you have fixed it.

Comment: it doesnt work on google chrome..

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be working fine

http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/5xER7/1/

```
.simply-scroll-list { 
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
    }
```